# SSL handshake failed when trying to run https code from c++

Tags: php, c++, qt, ssl, https

I am trying to use a c++ app to access a php script on a different computer.  The script queries a mysql database and outputs the values.  When accessing `https://myaddress/script.php` in my web browser, it gives me the "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" page, then allows me to Proceed Anyway.  I expected that, and it is ok because I have not yet jumped through the hoops to get my certificate certified.

However, when I try to access the same site from within my c++ app using QNetworkAccessManager, it tells me that the `SSL handshake failed` and quits out.

Why is this a problem? Does it have something to do with the fact that my certificate hasn't been authenticated, or is it something else? Can I set a feature in Qt Creator that allows my code to access even not trusted sites?

Any guidance would be very helpful, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you told qnetworkaccessmanager to allow the "bad" certificate? By default SSL libraries disallow that sort of thing, because a 'bad' certificate is a bad sign when encountered in the real world.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  I have tried things like 

`QList<QSslError> expectedSslErrors;

expectedSslErrors.append(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate);

expectedSslErrors.append(QSslError::CertificateUntrusted);

reply->ignoreSslErrors(expectedSslErrors);`

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I did two things:

re run/install Win32 OpenSSL Installation.
Download the latest "light" Win32 or Win64 installation package, for example "Win32 OpenSSL v0.9.8l Light".

follow link here:
   http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/234276-Qt-SSL-handshake-failed

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't appear to have done anything to fix my problem.  Is there some way I can check if the sslError is being sent out properly?  I have my connect setup (`connect(manager,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),this,SLOT(sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));`) but for some reason my `sslErrorHandler` method is never being called.

Comment: Basically, the link in above tells you to call ignoreSslErrors() in error handler. Can you check output window (I use visual studio), to see if there is any error message regarding signal slot connections?

Comment: Right now my only error output is `Error 6 SSL handshake failed`. I am not sure if the signal slot connection is correct.  How do I display slot errors?